# How to make a C program load store intensive?

Tags: c

How can the program be made intensively load-store so that there is maximum memory references and negligible computation(not even looping overheads!)

Answer (score 2):

With `gcc` use `-funroll-loops` on this code:

```
int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    int a = 5;
    int b = 10;
    int c;
    int i;

    while (1) {
        for (i = 0; i <= 2147483647; i++) {
            c = b;
            b = a;
            a = c;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks sharptooth, I always write retrun instead of return.

Answer (score 1):

Use huge arrays with a lot of scattered reads/writes to maximize cache misses. If your goal is to write a program that just exercises memory - write random values into an array at indices chosen randomly.

Comment: hey thnks a ton...is there any way to flush cache?

Comment: Haven't heard of, and if there is one, it is platform-dependent. However you don't really need it - scattered memory access does good job on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Use a lot of `volatile` variables, which are stored in-memory but I'm not sure if that answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Make a map between possible inputs to your program and possible outputs.

Calculations on the inputs to make the outputs need to be done by another program or by hand, though.